# How can I create two different topics with both topics having the same set of messages in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

To create a topic in Kafka the command is

```
bin/kafka-create-topic.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica 1 --partition 1  --topic test
```

This is easy. But how can i create two different topics with both both topics having the same set of messages in kafka?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you wanting one topic to be a copy of the other? Like one primary topic and then a backup topic? So if the primary topic is unavailable the backup topic will still (hopefully) be available?
2. Or do you just want them to have the same data and function independently of each other? So if you write to topic A, and Kafka automatically copies to topic B for you?

For #1, that's really what topic replication is for. Topic replication prevents losing service whenever a hardware failure occurs. Reading through the Kafka documentation should give a better sense of how replication works.

But for #2, multiple consumers can consume from the same topic and not effect the performance or place of other consumers in the same topic. Kafka doesn't provide a mechanism to automatically copy everything from topic A to topic B. You'd have to send the data twice to each topic, but I would recommend against that, using having multiple consumers consume from the same topic would be better way to get this functionality.